# Anyone using yui logger to track yui events? Is there a way to filter it?

Tags: javascript, debugging, logging, dom-events, yui

The problem that I'm having with it, is that it tracks all the events in the log reader, too. This makes it very difficult to work with. As I scroll up down, click or move in the reader to examine events, it's scrolling all over the place adding new events. Is there a way to filter it to only include certain events from certain sources? Am I likely doing something wrong? I'm using the 2.7 version with Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keith -- It sounds like you're using the -debug version of all of your files, is that correct?  If so, try including only the -debug version of the components with which you're most directly working (ie, user logger-min.js instead of logger-debug.js). -Eric

Comment: Thanks, that's probably it. When debugging, I just uncomment the debug filter in my yui loader section for ALL my modules. I'll pull that one out and load it separately (and others that I'm not currently debugging). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently. What I've done is to automatically hide all logger sources. You can then manually check the ones you want to view. Using YUI 2.7, this seems to do the trick:

```
//remove default sources
YAHOO.widget.Logger.sources = [];
var logger = new YAHOO.widget.LogReader();
//hide all sources loaded after the logger is instantiated
YAHOO.widget.Logger.sourceCreateEvent.subscribe(function(sType, aArgs, oSelf){     
  oSelf.hideSource(aArgs[0]);
}, logger);
```

Comment: I'll give that a try next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Eric's answer, I've found it's convenient for my workflow to use the [YUI loader filter configuration property](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/yuiloader/):

```
filter: { 
          'searchExp': "events-min\\.js", 
          'replaceStr': "events-debug.js"
      }
```

and just load the debug file that I'm interested in.